# Table view controller doesn't change custom class

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ibaction

I am trying to connect a bar button to view controller.h as a IBAction.  However I am not able to connect since the custom class does not change to view controller.h.  It is left blank and grey letters say UITableViewcontroller in the text box.  The navigation controller is also connected to the table view controller.  How can I change the custom class and why is this happening. Thank you. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried pasting your class name into the textfield that has the grey letters (i.e. the placeholder text)?

Comment: yes I did. It goes back to tableviewcontroller

Comment: Did you code any       [speventbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(create_Event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  :   or is everything in Interface Builder - please show your code if any